# Apache server control Python script

Tags: gpio, python, apache-httpd

I have a temperature sensor on my Raspberry Pi 2, I read the data with a python script. My question is how do I run that script on the Apache server (with a push of a button). Specifically how do I run a Python script through Apache server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you use the [CGI (Common Gateway Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).

The precise details of how you would use CGI depends on the script you want to use on the Pi.

There is a pigpio CGI example for my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library in these [Python examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_code).

There is a somewhat simpler method not involving pigpio or Apache if you run your own Python server on the Raspberry Pi.  There is example code called Easy as Pi Server at these [Miscellanous examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_code).  You'd need to look through the code example comments to see how it should be used.

Comment: Great, with webpy I can make it. Thx